# Google analytics goals with reveal.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, reveal.js

I'm using reveal.js (https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) which generates URL's with hash and the slide ID, for example: www.my-domain.com/#/slide1 > www.my-domain.com/#/slide2.

I want to set goals in Google Analytics for some slides, so I'll know the user reached to a certain point, how can I do that?

I tried using the full URL as a goal, but it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know reveal.js. but per [documentation](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) it comes with event listeners for interactions with the slides. There is an example for the Slide Changed event where you could  add event tracking code:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    // event.previousSlide, event.currentSlide, event.indexh, event.indexv
    ga('send', 'event', 'Slide', 'click', event.currentSlide);
} );
```

`event` is an object that gives you some information about the interaction via the object properties. Don't be confused by the fact that there is an "event" both in the GA tracking code and in the reveal.js code; the latter is a javascript event, the former is just a naming convention in Analytics (boradly speaking events are used to track stuff that does not trigger a page load).

Comment: That sounds like it should work, I'll try it. only one question: where do I see those custom events in Google Analytics?

Comment: @arielmorry In the behavior reports in the "events" section.